# How to capture screenshot with shadow using getDrawingCache?

Tags: java, android, imageview, shadow, elevation

I take screenshots within my app using:

```
private Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}
```

This works fine except that the result does not contain any shadow. How can I capture the shadows of elevated objects as well?

I think I can also make a fake shadow using a very old approach, but then this will be a very old approach and will neglect the concept of elevations and natural shadows. Which is I don't want.

Please reply.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it fits your case, but API > 21 has `MediaProjection` which allows taking screenshots / recording video. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture

Comment: Thank you, this is useful but not for my case. I want to save a screenshot for attachment purposes when the user clicks the share button in my app. So I wouldn't want my user to give a confirmation every time.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `UiDevice.takeScreenshot(File)` from UIAutomator.

You can try to implement [it's way](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/master/uiautomator/library/core-src/com/android/uiautomator/core/UiAutomatorBridge.java#108).
It uses [UiAutomation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/UiAutomation.html) that available only since API 18.

Comment: Is it used to take screenshots using the computer? I want to take screenshots and present to the user at execution time.

Comment: No, it takes screenshot by the device itself.

Comment: Can you please guide me more? I tried to search it but I can't figure out exactly what should I do.
I have tried UiAutomation.takeScreenshot(); but it gives error: "takeScreenshot" cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It looks like that UiAutomation can only be used in unit-tests, I've used it there. I also have some feelings that it can be used in normal applications with `instrumentation` tag in manifest and then `Instrumentation.getUiAutomation` but this doesn't looks good. Sorry :(